# Scrapy Shell Script failing

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy, scrapy-splash

I'm new to scraping and wanted to scrape some href links embedded in a web page. For some reason I can obtain the web links with xpath in the scrapy-splash shell but when I run this script it doesn't return the values I'm looking for. Can anyone help me identify what I'm doing wrong here? Here is the script:

```py
import scrapy
from scrapy_splash import SplashRequest


class CongressSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'congress_scraping'

    def start_requests(self):
        url = 'https://clerk.house.gov/Votes'
        yield SplashRequest(url=url, callback=self.parse, args={'screenshot': 1})

    def parse(self, response):
        # Extracting href links
        votes = response.xpath('//*[@id="votes"]//div')
        for vote in votes:
            roll_call_link = vote.xpath('.//div//a[contains(@aria-label, "Roll number")]//@href')
            print(roll_call_link)

            # Capturing screenshot
            screenshot_url = response.data.get('png')
            with open(f'screenshot_{roll_call_link}.png', 'wb') as f:
                f.write(response.body)

            yield {
                'Roll Call': roll_call_link,
                'Screenshot': screenshot_url
            }
```

And here is the result when I run the script:

```
2023-07-08 11:43:48 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 2.8.0 started (bot: congress)
2023-07-08 11:43:48 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Versions: lxml 4.9.1.0, libxml2 2.9.14, cssselect 1.1.0, parsel 1.6.0, w3lib 1.21.0, Twisted 22.2.0, Python 3.10.9 (main, Mar  1 2023, 12:33:47) [Clang 14.0.6 ], pyOpenSSL 23.0.0 (OpenSSL 1.1.1t  7 Feb 2023), cryptography 39.0.1, Platform macOS-10.16-x86_64-i386-64bit
2023-07-08 11:43:48 [scrapy.crawler] INFO: Overridden settings:
{'BOT_NAME': 'congress',
 'DUPEFILTER_CLASS': 'scrapy_splash.SplashAwareDupeFilter',
 'FEED_EXPORT_ENCODING': 'utf-8',
 'HTTPCACHE_STORAGE': 'scrapy_splash.SplashAwareFSCacheStorage',
 'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'congress.spiders',
 'REQUEST_FINGERPRINTER_IMPLEMENTATION': '2.7',
 'ROBOTSTXT_OBEY': True,
 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['congress.spiders'],
 'TWISTED_REACTOR': 'twisted.internet.asyncioreactor.AsyncioSelectorReactor'}
2023-07-08 11:43:48 [asyncio] DEBUG: Using selector: KqueueSelector
2023-07-08 11:43:48 [scrapy.utils.log] DEBUG: Using reactor: twisted.internet.asyncioreactor.AsyncioSelectorReactor
2023-07-08 11:43:48 [scrapy.utils.log] DEBUG: Using asyncio event loop: asyncio.unix_events._UnixSelectorEventLoop
2023-07-08 11:43:48 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet Password: 3f6ca2aac72c066f
2023-07-08 11:43:48 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled extensions:
['scrapy.extensions.corestats.CoreStats',
 'scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole',
 'scrapy.extensions.memusage.MemoryUsage',
 'scrapy.extensions.logstats.LogStats']
2023-07-08 11:43:48 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares:
['scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.robotstxt.RobotsTxtMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpauth.HttpAuthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.downloadtimeout.DownloadTimeoutMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.defaultheaders.DefaultHeadersMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.MetaRefreshMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.RedirectMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.cookies.CookiesMiddleware',
 'scrapy_splash.SplashCookiesMiddleware',
 'scrapy_splash.SplashMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.stats.DownloaderStats']
2023-07-08 11:43:48 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares:
['scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror.HttpErrorMiddleware',
 'scrapy_splash.SplashDeduplicateArgsMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite.OffsiteMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.referer.RefererMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.urllength.UrlLengthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth.DepthMiddleware']
2023-07-08 11:43:48 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
[]
2023-07-08 11:43:48 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2023-07-08 11:43:48 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2023-07-08 11:43:48 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2023-07-08 11:43:48 [py.warnings] WARNING: /Users/amitkumar/anaconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/scrapy_splash/dupefilter.py:20: ScrapyDeprecationWarning: Call to deprecated function scrapy.utils.request.request_fingerprint().

If you are using this function in a Scrapy component, and you are OK with users of your component changing the fingerprinting algorithm through settings, use crawler.request_fingerprinter.fingerprint() instead in your Scrapy component (you can get the crawler object from the 'from_crawler' class method).

Otherwise, consider using the scrapy.utils.request.fingerprint() function instead.

Either way, the resulting fingerprints will be returned as bytes, not as a string, and they will also be different from those generated by 'request_fingerprint()'. Before you switch, make sure that you understand the consequences of this (e.g. cache invalidation) and are OK with them; otherwise, consider implementing your own function which returns the same fingerprints as the deprecated 'request_fingerprint()' function.
  fp = request_fingerprint(request, include_headers=include_headers)

2023-07-08 11:43:48 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (404) <GET https://clerk.house.gov/robots.txt> (referer: None)
2023-07-08 11:43:48 [protego] DEBUG: Rule at line 1 without any user agent to enforce it on.
2023-07-08 11:43:48 [protego] DEBUG: Rule at line 2 without any user agent to enforce it on.
2023-07-08 11:43:48 [protego] DEBUG: Rule at line 8 without any user agent to enforce it on.
2023-07-08 11:43:48 [protego] DEBUG: Rule at line 9 without any user agent to enforce it on.
2023-07-08 11:43:48 [protego] DEBUG: Rule at line 10 without any user agent to enforce it on.
2023-07-08 11:43:48 [protego] DEBUG: Rule at line 11 without any user agent to enforce it on.
2023-07-08 11:43:48 [protego] DEBUG: Rule at line 12 without any user agent to enforce it on.
2023-07-08 11:43:52 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://clerk.house.gov/Votes via http://localhost:8050/render.html> (referer: None)
2023-07-08 11:43:52 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2023-07-08 11:43:52 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 766,
 'downloader/request_count': 2,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 1,
 'downloader/request_method_count/POST': 1,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 114026,
 'downloader/response_count': 2,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 1,
 'downloader/response_status_count/404': 1,
 'elapsed_time_seconds': 4.234632,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2023, 7, 8, 15, 43, 52, 845644),
 'log_count/DEBUG': 12,
 'log_count/INFO': 10,
 'log_count/WARNING': 1,
 'memusage/max': 61034496,
 'memusage/startup': 61034496,
 'response_received_count': 2,
 'robotstxt/request_count': 1,
 'robotstxt/response_count': 1,
 'robotstxt/response_status_count/404': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 2,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 2,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 2,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 2,
 'splash/render.html/request_count': 1,
 'splash/render.html/response_count/200': 1,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2023, 7, 8, 15, 43, 48, 611012)}
2023-07-08 11:43:52 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```